# How do I get PHP to convert a blank field in MySQL to "0"?

Tags: php, mysql, sequence

I have created a field in MySQL named "pid", which I use in PHP coding at the end of other variable names to indicate which of 7 template designs a user has created. The limit is 7, at which point they are given a message that they have reached their limit.

I have the code working EXCEPT when the field is blank (before user creates the first template). When I hard-code a "0" it works. But, obviously, I need to use the "{pid}" variable to pick up the template sequence in the database.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?PHP
  $pid = {pid};
  $total_templates = 7;
  if ($total_templates > $pid) {
    echo "<a href='create.template.php'><img src='create_template.png'></a>";
  } else {
    echo "<b style='color: #CC0000'>Your limit of $pid Templates has been reached";
  }
?>
```

How do I get the code to convert a blank field in MySQL to "0" in conjunction with the above code?

Comment: Show the SQL query. Blank may be 'blank' to you, or it may be `NULL` to SQL/PHP.

Comment: `if( $pid == "" ) { $pid = 0; }`

Comment: Are you looking for a one time fix of the database or something that will check user input and convert it to "0" before storing in the database?

Comment: Unrelated: the `b` element is deprecated. You want a more semantic element? `<span class="error">` and use CSS like a sane person.

Comment: @Shredder I assume you mean by clicking YES to the question "Was this post useful to you?" at the end of the answers, correct? If so, I have gone through and done this with all previous questions. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, could you not set it to `0` if it is `empty()`?

```
$pid={pid};
if(empty($pid))
    $pid = 0;
```

You can also set the default value for that field in mysql. If you are using phpAdmin, go to the table and click the "Change" action and set the default value there. If you need sql command to do this, I can get that for you too.

Comment: I thought this would have worked. But the code is seeing `$pid=;` when the field is blank and throwing a Parse error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';') before it gets to the `if` statement.

Comment: Could you show me where you get `{pid}` from? That would greatly help; I have not seen that before.

Comment: I'm trying to patch someone else's code, which creates tags from all the field names for inserting throughout html pages. All tags are enclosed within these brackets {}. Which file or line of code that is doing this, I'm not sure. It could b `replace_tags_t($q->f("field_name"), $t);`

Comment: Hmm..that seems to be a user defined function. Sorry; if you could show me how these tags are created, I could be more help. If you think they are created in the function, could you find the function definition and edit that in your post?

Comment: When I try doing something like `$myvar = {myvar};` I get error `syntax error, unexpected '{'`. Strange. Does this application use [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)? Maybe that's it.

Comment: Could you try my original answer? `$pid = (empty({pid})) ? 0 : {pid};` - If it is using some kind of API, maybe that would work for you.

Comment: @ Shredder I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$'` when using your original answer. I'm not sure how or what was used by the original coders.

Comment: >< Ok, well if you update all the empty fields to 0, and change mysql to use default 0 and `not null` for that column, you shouldn't run into this problem.

Comment: Yep, thanks @ Shredder. That seemed to have fixed the problem (ie, changing mysql default value to 0).... Sheeeeesh, I need a swift kick in the backsides this morning :(

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to set the default value in mysql to 0.  Then you will have no issues.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use `intval` in order to force it as an integer. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php.

```
if ($total_templates > intval($pid))
```

Although I would just set the default value of the pid field to 0 in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ternary operator to set the `$pid` value
`$pid = ({pid} != '' ? {pid} : '0');`

If there is a real value on `$pid` it'll display it, else it'll display 0, I haven't tested this code.

A better approach would be to set a default value for that field in your SQL.

For more info about the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: The problem is I'm getting this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'" because the `{pid}` variable is blank, hence the code sees `$pid=;` instead of having some integer, such as `$pid=0;`

Comment: @ afarzit I tried it. But the problem is it isn't getting past the `$pid={pid};` when `{pid}` is blank (which causes it to see `$pid=;`, and throws the Parse error mentioned above.

Comment: @user1322707 i've misunderstood your question at first. Try the changes i've made.